# failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, firewall

I want using nginx make reverse proxy(docker container). However, there have been some exceptions.

***issue context***

- Centos version: 7.4.1708
- nginx version: 1.13.12
- docker version: 1.13.1

#### Open firewall and exposed 80 port

- nginx reproxy on docker container: failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream
- nginx reproxy on host: function normal

***nginx configuration:***

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name web.pfneo.geo;
    location / {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://172.18.0.249:88;
    }
    access_log logs/web.tk_access.log;
}
```

#### close the firewall

- nginx reproxy on docker container: function normal
- nginx reproxy on host: function normal

#### Open firewall not expose port

- nginx app service on docker container（88 port）: function normal

> It seems that this problem is caused by docker?
>
> Docker can ignore the host firewall?